# comparing data among different tables using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following is a lab question, so please don't post direct answers, but rather point out what part of my logic process is wrong

Given the following tables

**director** (id, production_year, title)

**person** (id, first_name, last_name, year_born)

**role** (credits, description, id, production_year, title)

**movie** (country, genre, production_year, run_time, title)

The Question is "List all directors who have played a role in movies not directed by them"

My Attempt is the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first_name, p.last_name
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM role r, director d WHERE p.id = d.id AND p.id=r.id AND r.title <> d.title)
```

I am thinking " Given any person, return that person's first_name and last_name if

1. that person is both a director **(p.id = d.id)** and a actor with a role **(p.id = r.id)**, and
2. The movie this person is playing a role in is not a movie that this person has directed **(r.title <> d.title)**"

Is there anything wrong with my logic or my syntax? Right now I am getting 7 names back, but apparently the correct result only has 3 names

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your syntax is old-style - I haven't seen that for ages.  New standards are

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable
INNER JOIN SubTable on SubTable.MainTableId = MainTable.Id
```

But I think the problem is that you should be saying more like "select a person who IS a director and IS in a role, but the role he is in is not in (the list of movies he directed)".

Also, in real life, it's unlikely that the person's ID will be the same as the director's ID - there are many more people than actors, and the ID is typically auto-incremented by the database on insert.  However, looking at your tables, it looks like this is not an issue because both your role.id and director.id should be renamed to role.personId and director.personId.